# Download file, retrieved from port on the local server

Tags: php, couchdb

I had some trouble explaining my question in short for the title, so here the full explanation.

I'm exploring [couchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) for a schoolproject and have come across a probably small issue.
On the server I'm able to retrieve a file from http://localhost:5984/bibliography/c452b83c3a3dd1ce5b13f18b37000aa3/3567149.pdf
I created a link to this using a button:.

```
<a style="text-align:left" href="http://localhost:5984/bibliography/c452b83c3a3dd1ce5b13f18b37000aa3/3567149.pdf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
3567149.pdf
</a>
```

This was no problem whilst I was running the application on my local machine, but this doesn't work on my VPS, since this port is not accessible from the outside.

I think my best option would be to retrieve the file using php, and then prompt the user to download it. But I can't find out how to do this.

Comment: Is the PHP server on your localhost public to your entire VPS? You could use cURL to download the file... probably, and then just spit it out with the right MIME types.

Comment: What is the value of the parameter `bind_address` in your CouchDB configuration?